# Is there a better way to deal with low-quality questions that have a bounty attached?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, bounty

[This question (*How do I create an infinite loop?*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518226/how-do-i-create-an-infinite-loop) has a whopping **500 Point Bounty** on it. The question is, as you may have guessed, exactly that - the user has no idea what an infinite loop is.

It even *appears to be a homework question*.

It's extremely low quality and should be closed, but obviously cannot because it has an open bounty.

The user that placed the bounty doesn't even seem to care.

> are you the bounty police now? why do you care? my rep is my rep to do with what I wish.

---

I'm not here to ask something be done to the question. I'm here to ask something be done to Stack Overflow.

These questions should be closed and disregarded as incredibly low quality. By adding a bounty on it, *it's encouraging new users that these are OK questions that will get them lots of reputation*.

Aside from the bounty, keeping them open to begin with is doing the same.

Please, could we discuss a way to circumvent such things? Such as removing the abused non-closable open bounty constraint on questions?

This is getting out of hand.

Comment: The comments got a bit off-topic so this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105614/discussion-on-question-by-qix-these-cannot-close-questions-with-a-bounty-posts).

Comment: Posting the question on Meta was obviously enough to gain some attention and get it closed. Now it is a duplicate

Comment: Wow, -27 score on the question (and the duplicate target from three years ago has +18 score...). Do you people have no mercy?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker totally agree that meta pile on is out of proportion

Comment: Referenced in *[Tired of Stack Overflow](https://arp242.net/stackoverflow.html)*.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The way you deal with such questions is to cast a custom moderator flag on the question and explain the problem, just as was done here.

No need for a software overhaul.  Flags of this type are typically dealt with expeditiously and fairly.

Comment: Agreed. Glad to know it is indeed a valid flaggable concern for the mods. That was my concern in the OP.

Comment: Are flags on bountiedquestions, or mentioning bounties, in any way prioritized (should they be if they aren't)? Whether they are or not, how long should one expect that to take?

Answer (score 65):

The 500 rep bounty is suspicious. Martijn said he handled it and that's that. But perhaps equally important here:

> It's extremely low quality and should be closed

Why?

- The question is about programming.
- The question is understandable.
- It's a specific and answerable question.
- The author made some effort to solve the problem and included code.

Yes, it's a basic question. Some might even call it a "stupid question", and that's perhaps not entirely unfair. But does that mean we need to "close" all those questions that are deemed "too stupid"? I don't see anything about that in the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page.

You don't like the question? Downvote and move on.

> It even *appears to be a homework question*.

So? Nothing wrong with asking help for homework, as long as it's not a "plz do my homework for me kthxbye"-sort of question (which this isn't).

Arguably, those are the questions that should be focused on *more*, as here there is a chance to really teach someone something.

Comment: `You don't like the question? Downvote and move on.` I disagree. This is very much one of the issues I have with SO - downvoting by itself does very little in terms of quality control for the site. However, +1 for `those are the questions that should be focused on more, as here there is a chance to really teach someone something.`.

Comment: @Qix Your sense of "quality" might not be the same that someone else may have. You may be looking for interesting and challenging questions to answer so that *you* yourself can learn in answering. That's okay. Other people might be looking for an opportunity to explain and teach basic skills. That's *also* okay. It doesn't mean that a question is of "low quality", just that it's a different sort of question than you like to answer...

Comment: Not exactly; there are a ton of those questions on SO as it is and most of them are closed. Normally you are correct - an 'easy' question isn't inherently a low quality question. [A good example of that here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15182397/510036). Asking how to make an endless loop is, especially when it was admitted by the OP it was coming from a homework question.

Comment: @Qix I respectfully disagree. It's not a stellar question, or even a "good" question. But it's not a "low quality" question in the sense that it needs to be closed. I can understand someone not understanding the concept of an "infinite" loop, as basic as that may seem to you and me.

Comment: I concur, @Qix: if you find a question too *trivial*, then it can only be closed if it is a duplicate. Odds are, it is. Otherwise well-posed questions about very simple problems are hard to close (since we don't have an "RTFM or read *any* tutorial whatsoever" close reason). There used to be a close reason along the lines of "fails to demonstrate basic understanding of the problem being solved", but it's said to be regularly misused (so the reason has been removed).

Comment: +1 for "here is a chance to really teach someone something"

Comment: I was always told in school, "the only stupid question is the question you don't ask".

Answer (score 13):

*This is a summary of the discussion that took place [in this post's chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105614/discussion-on-question-by-qix-these-cannot-close-questions-with-a-bounty-posts). These are not my opinions.*

---

The question I linked to was the subject of a suspected (and I assume now confirmed, judging from the action taken by moderators) bounty fraud ring.

Evidence of such can be found in at least one chat transcript, linked by the moderators that carried out the actions themselves.

Simply put, the users in question had their bounties removed - the posts in question are now eligible for closing if the community finds it fit.

---

As per the moderators, this was a scenario of users trading bounties. [Clear advice](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29187213#29187213) from moderators for users asking about it in the future:

> Robert Harvey: Don't trade bounties. There's your clear and concise guidance.

It has now become clear that more investigation was taking place outside of SO/SO.meta proper, and the current problem has been remedied.

In the future, a moderator flag would be the correct course of action to be taken.