# How to deal with the duplicate questions which also have bounty on them?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, bounty

Today I came across this question

[Printing rows from database into a list view in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448158/printing-rows-from-database-into-a-list-view-in-android-studio)

as you can see there is an open bounty of 50 Reputation on this question now. But there has been a similar question asked related to this. Here is that question

[“ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView” xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

By going through the StackTrace mentioned in questions and with little expertise in Android it is very clear that they both are the same questions.

I tried to flag the question. But a pop up came saying that

> This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed

So, In this situation what needs to be done? Is answering those kinds of questions still encouraged?

Or the existing feature can be removed or users with some defined reputations can be allowed to flag questions having bounty?

I also checked this one [Is there a better way to deal with low-quality questions that have a bounty attached?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318482/is-there-a-better-way-to-deal-with-low-quality-questions-that-have-a-bounty-atta)
The accepted answer says *we should rise a custom moderation flag on that kind of question.*
Is the same thing need to followed in this case as well?

Or what is the appropriate step that can be taken in this case?

Thank You.

Comment: Yes, you handle it the same way. The reason why a bountied question should be closed doesn't matter. It is worth looking at the remaining time left for the bounty. When  it is close to expiring better wait it out and revisit after the bounty is gone and close vote.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate is an even *stronger* case for allowing the community to cast close votes on questions with an active bounty. Duplicate closure is one of the few close reasons that requires some sort of subject-matter expertise, so it'll be even less likely that a moderator would respond to a custom flag requesting that a bounty be removed in order to close a question as a duplicate. It would require either that the duplicate is so obvious anyone could tell it was a duplicate, or that you happened to get a moderator who knows something about the subject matter.

Comment: Why cant' the boundy not reward the person who solved the problem by finding the duplicate?

Comment: @IanRingrose I think that will be too easy and require less effort