# Close this low quality question with a bounty on it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags, bounty

According to this [Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318482/1244884)  I should simply  cast a custom moderator flag. I've done this for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53085793/1244884) but my flag got declined with the following comment from the moderator:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

FYI the full content of the question is this:

> How to create bitcoin cash private key, wallet and address with bitcoincashjs javascript library ?

Ideally should have been closed *before* the bounty was set but now that is has one I cannot cast a vote to close it and the moderator has declined my flag so ‍♂️

Comment: I wonder who put a bounty on that?

Comment: The bounty is almost over and I know that some moderators are disinclined to cancel bounties which are almost complete. That said that standard decline reason does not clearly indicate why flagging was not appropriate in this case. That said, I don’t know what your flag text looked like, nor what the mod UI shows. If you just asked for the question to be closed without mentioning the bounty I can see a flag like that being declined with this reason.

Comment: @HenryEcker Here's was my justification for it when casting the flag: `Without a bounty on it this question would probably have been closed as needing more focus.`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146366/coderama) user offered the bounty. The irony of a user with 16K reputation offering a bounty an obviously bad out of scope question does not escape me

Comment: Seems weird to bounty a 3.5 year old question about a library that seems to be no longer maintained. *shrug*

Comment: @SecurityHound, users with 100K+ reputation *answer* obviously bad and/or out of scope questions without bounty to gain reputation points. spending 100 points on bounty *when site allows it* is just logical thing to do when facing the same issue.

Comment: bounty purspose is stated as "draw more attention". well, the question certainly got attention :D

Comment: There's an urgent need for ```flag this bounty``` option.

Comment: @SalmanMalik That option already exists. It's labeled "in need of moderator intervention". While it would be beneficial to have some more base flag types, and to allow explanations to be optionally provided on at least some other flag types, flagging to request removing a bounty isn't all that high on the list of ones it might be nice to have as separate flags. Admittedly, it might be helpful, but there are various other types of flags which currently use "in need of moderator intervention" which are much more common than this issue and would be ones I'd choose as a named flag before this.

Comment: As the person who placed the bounty, I'm quite amazed by the debate it has caused. For anyone who is wondering, yes, I should have probably opened a new question with more details rather than giving a bounty. But I try not to open new questions unless necessary. Next time I'll get it right ;-)

Answer (score 17):

The text of your flag said:

> Without a bounty on it this question would probably have been closed as needing more focus.

That's more of a statement rather than a particular action that you want mods to take. Reading between the lines, if you wanted the question to be closed by mods, then the decline reason applies. You can just wait a day and cast your close vote yourself. There was no need to involve moderators there.

Moderators don't refund bounties that are almost over. Unless there's a good reason why the question should be immediately deleted, then it's better to just wait the remaining time and vote to close the question the normal way. It's ok to ask mods to refund a fresh bounty if it was posted to prevent question closure; that's an issue that moderators should be made aware of and we will act upon it. But if you only think the question would have been closed if not for the bounty, it's not really a reason to involve moderators.

Comment: To be honest I didn't pay attention to the expiry date of the bounty. My bad; makes sense. Just for the record: I didn't expect anything else other than just the closing of the question. It's obviously a bad one and if the user loses their bounty in full because of that then so be it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do mods not have the ability to close a bountied question without refunding the bounty (i.e., cancel it)?

Comment: @41686d6564 that is correct.  We must refund a bounty in order to close the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the time remaining being a factor to refund/close a question that likely shouldn't have ever had a bounty on it in the first place come down to mod preference? You'd think it would provide the most benefit to close/delete these garbage questions as early as possible. If the bounty was placed to keep the question from being closed/deleted does it matter that much if it's "caught" on day 1 or day 6?

Comment: @DrewReese it's definitely a moderator preference thing, yeah.  The idea is that with a bounty, you're paying for exposure for the question.  If it's day 6, you've already gotten the vast majority of what you paid for, so refunding the price paid because the question is bad sort of means that people can get free exposure for bad questions, but exposure for good questions actually costs reputation.  And that's not really the incentive structure we want.

Comment: @RyanM Your answer certainly made it more clear (*to me*) that in this situation you should *really* spell it out "the why" for the mod message. Correct me if I'm wrong, if a member, after having paid for the exposure of their question, has no takers, no answers, etc... , they are refunded the bounty amount? The [/help/bounty](/help/bounty) page isn't clear what happens to the bounty other than "If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone." If the net result is no answer, is the bounty refunded, or considered "spent"?

Comment: @DrewReese if they don't receive an answer, the bounty cost is still spent.  The reputation simply goes away.

Comment: @RyanM Ah, I see then, it makes sense to let the post/bounty age out and the asker incur the cost. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: "Unless there's a good reason why the question should be immediately deleted"  Can you name a reason why it _shouldn't_ be immediately deleted? This is a very bad question and preserving it holds no value. The flag was correct and this shouldn't have been declined. It's not the users' fault that the bounty system has a broken moderation API.

Comment: @Lundin I am not an expert in that API so I don't know if it should be closed. Even if it didn't have an active bounty I would probably still not vote to close. See Ryan M's answer below for more information.

Comment: @Dharman As I replied there as well, you don't have to be an expert to immediately realize that this should be closed. Also the bounty mechanism shouldn't be abused as a means to keep crap questions open.

Comment: @Lundin The question was open for over 3 years, so the bounty is not an abuse of the system. The question is asking "how to" and it seems clear enough to me. IMHO I don't see a reason to close it. There's always some subjectivity when it comes to closing, but I wouldn't say that this one is obvious.

Comment: Seriously? Then what's your definition of a too broad question, if this isn't one? I can rephrase it slightly: "Can you give me the complete code for how to create bitcoin cash private key, wallet and address with bitcoincashjs javascript library?" The _only_ difference between this question and the one in the link is that I've now clarified that no effort or research have been made or will be made. So it's actually an improvement...

Comment: @Lundin I can't tell you if you need to write a whole tutorial to explain how to do this or if it's only a couple lines of code. It might be as simple as calling one function. There's no research or effort necessary from the author because the question seems clear to me without it. But I don't know how to do it either. I assume that's the whole reason why someone posted a bounty. They also want to know how to do it.

Comment: A question that lacks focus means that a good answer would need to be a whole book to explain the topic properly. The official description says "it includes multiple questions". We require askers to focus on a single problem that can be answered in the available answer space. An effort to try something is absolutely not necessary from the asker.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. If it's a simple thing that can be achieved by just calling a function, then in that case the op should be able to quickly figure it out by RTFM and in that case it boils down to "where can I find basic study material" instead. That's not a question we should answer or need to preserve either.

Comment: And no matter how we put it, it's not some great loss to the site if this question was just deleted. If someone truly and desperately needs an answer to it, then they can post a new, better question, simple as that. My stand vs the "crap huggers" in the endless debate here on meta is always: _we do not need to preserve crap just for the sake of it_.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Dharman's answer: this question *is* focused...or, at least, not so clearly unfocused as to warrant unilateral moderator closure (though it could use some editing).

I don't know much about the intricacies of cryptocurrency<sup>1</sup>, but my understanding is that "private key, wallet and address" are all more or less the same thing - you generate a private key, which has a derived public key, and the address is derived from the hash of the public key, and the balance stored at that address is the wallet.  So these are really a single task, which turns out to be [4 lines of code](https://github.com/jbdtky/bitcoincashjs/blob/master/docs/examples.md#generate-a-random-address), [as discovered by Abdul Aziz Barkat in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419109/close-this-low-quality-question-with-a-bounty-on-it/419112#comment917658_419112).

The above explanation of why it's focused may be inaccurate, because, again, I'm not a subject matter expert.  But that's also sort of the point: **when you're asking moderators to close a question with a bounty, your flag is pretty unlikely to be handled by someone who's an expert on the subject matter**.  There are quite a lot of topics discussed here, and while we're experts on some, there aren't enough of us to cover everything—and which one of us you get is somewhat random.

Basically, **if you're flagging a bountied question for moderator closure, please make sure it's *obvious***.

---

<sup>1 [Web3 is going just great](https://web3isgoinggreat.com/) being of particular relevance to why.</sup>

Comment: I would have voted to close that question as "needs focus", because there's no indication of what part of the process of using that library they are stuck on. I would expect the question to show the code they had written so far, and explain how its results were unexpected.

Comment: (but I appreciate that closing for that reason isn't really a moderator's job)

Comment: I really don't agree with the suggestion that the question is focused but your comment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419109/close-this-low-quality-question-with-a-bounty-on-it#comment917591_419110) makes sense to me though ;) Didn't see it that way. Thanks.

Comment: The question is very clearly too broad and cannot be salvaged by anyone but the OP. You don't have to be a domain expert to tell that. "How do I do my whole project? I have made zero effort and zero research" is always a question that should be closed.

Comment: "*I have made zero effort and zero research*" That's definitely not a reason to close a question. The asker doesn't need to show an effort of what they tried if it's not relevant to the question. This question might be too broad, but it's not asking to write a whole application, so you would need an expert to know if this question can be answered in the current form.

Comment: @Dharman Are you serious? This is a straight-up "gimme the code" question. I have no experience with any of those tags and it should be completely obvious to anyone with experience on Stack Overflow what it is. The question should be closed. There shouldn't be a doubt in your mind about it. If they *try to implement something* and it's not working, they should provide a [mcve] and clearly explain what's not working, then they'll have a valid question. Please don't encourage terrible questions.

Comment: @mason What's wrong with "gimme the code" question? That's one of the best questions we could have on Stack Overflow. I much prefer questions like this than debugging questions which are more localized. It's pretty much the purpose of Stack Overflow to provide solutions to common programming problems.

Comment: @Dharman This isn't a *programming problem*. It's an application description. It's no more on topic than "How do I create a blog website using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework?". It's not a matter of *what you prefer*. It's a matter of what the standards of our site are, and you're really diluting the purpose here if you keep encouraging "gimme the code" questions like that.

Comment: @mason assuming my description of the relevant concepts is correct, how much more focused could it be?  It's more or less asking "how do I generate a new Bitcoin Cash key and get the address for it?"  It's not like Ethereum where a wallet can actually be an application in itself.

Comment: This is why I am saying that I don't know the topic and I would not vote to close this question. It might very well be unfocused and asking for too much, but I can't know that. What I know is that questions like that are generally very much on-topic and "lack of effort" is not a close reason.

Comment: @RyanM They should have attempted to actually write the application. That means breaking down their application into specific tasks (plan) and then attempt to actually implement it. If they get stuck on a particular part, create a [mcve] and clearly explain what they're trying to do and what's not working about it.

Comment: @Dharman Lack of effort isn't a close reason, but an overly broad question asking how to implement a bunch of things is a valid close reason. The way to make it on-topic is to actually put effort in and attempt something.

Comment: @mason They did: the part they are stuck on is _creating a new Bitcoin Cash wallet and getting its private key and address_.  This is like saying that someone trying to [access command-line arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4033723/208273) should try to write a Python application that accesses command-line arguments and report where they get stuck (I'd guess they would get stuck on the "access command line arguments" bit).  Presumably, they've already tried, and they can't figure out *how* to do it.

Comment: @RyanM If they've already tried, they need to show *what they've tried* and clearly explain what's not working about their attempt. You say presumably they tried, but that's just it - you've assumed. Until you see actual evidence presented with a clear problem, then it's not a reasonably scoped question. We don't know what the problem is, because we can't see what they've tried. So, it should be closed. If they edit their attempt into the question and show us what problem they're having, that would make it valid.

Comment: @mason you're essentially saying is that the question should be closed for lack of _evidence_ of effort.  This is exactly the same as closing a question for lack of effort.

Comment: @RyanM No, I am not saying that it should be closed for lack of evidence of effort. I'm saying that it should be closed because it's not a reasonably scoped question, and the way to fix it is to put in some effort and then show what's not working about their attempt. Can you see the difference?

Comment: By putting in some effort, they'll either end up with what they want (hooray!) or they'll run into a specific issue they're unable to solve, which will give them a valid question to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mason Is your argument that it should be broken up into multiple questions about creating the wallet, getting the address, and getting the private key?  But...evidence of effort wouldn't help with that.  Simply reducing the scope of the question would.  It would be far better to focus on *that* than the need to show what they've tried (though I still believe this is one focused task, as the comment below this shows: it's 4 lines of code). 
 Questions that ask for debugging assistance often end up reducing to simple logic errors that will never help anyone else with the same task.

Comment: @mason I'm not an SME but a little bit of searching shows this [example](https://github.com/jbdtky/bitcoincashjs/blob/master/docs/examples.md#generate-a-random-address) on the libraries GitHub, I don't see how the question lacks focus if that's all that is needed to answer the question. As already stated above "Lack of effort isn't a close reason"

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ...sounds like you could go claim a bounty if you wanted :-)

Comment: @RyanM ah, well I am not an SME (never really worked with Blockchain), don't want to end up embarrassing myself :).

Comment: @RyanM, No, my argument isn't that it should be broken up. My argument is that there's no clear problem statement, therefore it's not reasonably scoped, and therefore should be closed. The user needs to have a clear problem statement on their question in order to be valid. They might run into a new issue after they receive a solution for whatever their first problem is, and then they can create a new question so long as that too had a reasonably scoped problem statement.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You found a library, same as the user could have. That's good, now they need to actually try using it. Then, if they run into a problem implementing the library that they're unable to resolve, they can show what they've tried with that library and what's not working about it. That would make it a reasonably scoped question.

Comment: @mason the question specifically asks _how to do so with this library_.  It is very clearly written in the very short problem description.

Comment: @RyanM Then they should show the code that they've attempted to write and clearly explain *what's not working* about the attempt. This is no different than any other question that says something is "not working" without showing what they've tried and what's not working about it: it should be closed.

Comment: @mason code and/or attempt isn't needed if they haven't indicated that they've ran into a problem with implementation.

Comment: @KevinB Then the question isn't reasonably scoped, there's no clear problem statement. It's an application description. I'm not saying that all questions require code, just that they must be reasonably scoped, and that on this particular question, it's too broad.

Comment: @mason ***SO isn't a debugging service***. Not every question has to be "How do i fix this error" or "correct this code". "How do i do X" is a valid question without attempts.

Comment: @KevinB Not, that's not necessarily valid if it's too broad in scope. It must be reasonably scoped. How do I create a blog using ASP.NET and Entity Framework? How do I implement machine learning with Python and TensorFlow? How do I create a Bitcoin wallet with bitcoincashjs? None of those are reasonably scoped.

Comment: I'd categorize smething that can be solved in 4 lines as being quite different from building an entire website.

Answer (score -6):

This question lacks a clear *problem statement*, and should have been closed before the bounty was offered. And once the bounty was offered, contrary to what the elected moderators are saying, it should have been closed by them.

Yes, it has a clear objective, but it's *not a problem statement*. It's an application description. Surrounding an application description with a "How to..." and a question mark doesn't make it a reasonably scoped question.

How to questions *can* be on-topic here, but they must be reasonably scoped, inline with [guidance on this subject](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413152/is-it-possible-to-ask-general-how-to-questions). This particular question was not reasonably scoped, as to answer it you'd have to implement an entire application to do it. This doesn't require expert domain knowledge on the subject.

What the user should have done was make an actual attempt to implement their application. If they get stuck on a particular part of their implementation, they should create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and clearly explain what their objective is and what's not working about their attempt. That would give them a reasonably scoped question.

All the talk about returning the bounty points should be secondary to the primary objective of cleaning up bad questions. If the system doesn't allow elected moderators to cancel a bounty without returning the points, then that's a feature enhancement that the developers need to implement.

Comment: They did: the part they are stuck on is _creating a new Bitcoin Cash wallet and getting its private key and address_.  This is like saying that someone trying to [access command-line arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4033723/208273) should try to write a Python application that accesses command-line arguments and report where they get stuck (I'd guess they would get stuck on the "access command line arguments" bit).  Presumably, they've already tried, and they can't figure out *how* to do it.

Comment: @RyanM Yes, exactly! If I'm having trouble with consuming command line arguments in Python, I should show what I've tried and clearly explain the issue I'm running into. That would give a clear problem statement and thus be a valid question.

Comment: Can we please stop trying to turn every *general* question into a *specific* debugging question? "How to do X?" is useful to tons of people; "Why does ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ not do X?" is useful to practically no one but the OP. Yes, questions may lack focus or otherwise fail to be specific enough; No, that does not mean that an attempt is needed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi For the most part it seems all the easy "How to do X?" questions have already been asked/answered, with hundreds or thousands of votes, and duplicates. We don't need more of them as they are generally overly broad and ***should*** probably be voted on accordingly. When I come across "How to do X" questions my go-to comment is typically "Well, SO isn't a code writing service, what have you tried? What is the issue?". If we see what they are *trying* to do it is often obvious and easy to point them to duplicates, or VTC needing more details if they fail to provide it.