# How should I handle this question having bounty needs to solve an XY problem?

Tags: discussion, bounty, xy-problem

I proposed two solutions to this [bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73161459/15993687), *both* of which were negatively taken by the author of the question. At the time of writing the answer, the question itself lacked proper information on what the author expected (I indeed thought I understood the requirements, which is why I answered).

The author expects to pass two placeholder variables to an [f-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) in a different file without creating a function or modifying the variable.

Example of what I mean:

*template.py* file

```
test_template = f"Bla bla bla {article} {subject}"
```

*main.py*

```
from template import test_template

template1 = Template.test_template
```

I understood that this wasn't technically possible. Now, even after several edits to the question, it still remains unclear, and the author isn't ready to compromise on that (the test_template). I can't possibly flag this question as needing details or clarity as the bounty is still in progress. What else can I do to inform other users, so they will not have to waste their time on this XY problem that has a bounty?

Comment: Why should you? The whole point of a bounty is to attract attention to something difficult. People who are looking for bountied questions should expect to not find something that'll take more than a minute to not only answer but also process.

Comment: As the bounty is still fresh, I'd strongly recommend that you flag the post for moderator attention. I would probably go with something like this: _"The question does not have enough details to be answered, but it cannot be closed due to the active bounty"_.

Comment: @Gimby What do you mean? It's indeed a simple problem to solve; the author lacks a basic understanding of programming; read through it. It isn't difficult or impossible. The author just makes it impossible to answer.

Comment: In truth, if the problem is an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) then closure based solely on that isn't the right solution anyway, *Y* can still be an on-topic question. If X has been correctly identified, then the "best" answer would be to explain why Y is wrong, explain and provide a solution for X, and give a solution for Y demonstrating it's flaws or "incorrectness". Otherwise at least get the OP to edit their question to ask X instead of Y (and ask for a clean up of commons). Asking an XY problem isn't a closure reason if Y is still well asked.

Comment: If you just want to inform people, leave a comment explaining your thoughts. If people don't want to read that comment (for bountied questions, i think it important you do read all the comments) , then they are free to try to answer the question. The fact that the 3 answers on the question are deleted as well would mean that they can't serve as a flag to denote what the OP isn't asking. (If you do undelete any of the answers, please flag the "FOR THE READERS: if you read, can you also write me your answer?" comments as no longer needed)

Comment: @Art See it like this. The author had a question which was not receiving attention/answers, so they bountied it. Everything is going according to plan right? Your diagnosis is that the question is an XY problem, so that makes everything problematic. That state needs to be corrected first. Now from what I can tell then the state then becomes an impossible task. So how do we handle those? In my experience we do not, because only few people will have the skill and the heart to write an answer stating empirically it is not possible. So my expected outcome of this is the bounty period expiring.

Comment: @E_net4-MrDownvoter that flag would almost certainly be declined on this question.  [Mods aren't subject-matter experts on every technology](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419112/208273), and we need to be very confident we're correct if we're going to unilaterally refund a bounty and close a question.  The question seems to contain many details, so it's not immediately clear what details it's missing.  At the very least, you need to explain _why_ the question lacks enough detail that it can't be answered in the flag.

Comment: A flag that someone raised on that question asking to close it said, in part, "The author is expecting to write code for him/her, not trying to seek any help, or looking to learn" - none of these are reasons to close a question.  Most questions here are answered by writing code, and we don't care about the asker's motives; we care only if the question is clear, reasonably scoped, on-topic, and not a duplicate.

Comment: I've been over this question. It's a mess on several levels: it lacks an MRE and it's unclear exactly what restrictions OP has in mind on how things should work. I didn't even notice the f-string problem when I was taking a shot at improving it. It's also extremely unfocused: it basically boils down to "please resolve the problem that is making this code dump not work". There are many possible approaches to how to organize the code to avoid the circular import, but no way to guess which ones would or wouldn't satisfy the OP.

Comment: OP has also refused to try to isolate the problem or work on an MRE, flatly asserting that certain things are essential to the problem when I know that not to be the case. Please also look at the revision history - I put considerable work into trying to remove redundancy and organize the question so that it's at least understandable, only for OP to make a series of edits re-adding a bunch of irrelevant detail.

Comment: It's not *just* that OP wants custom-written code - OP actively resists the question being made into something that meets our not-a-discussion-forum standards.

Comment: @RyanM, I flagged that; I didn't flag it for close, I was hoping the author to rephrase and rewrite the entire question with detail and clarity and be open to solutions different than what the user expects. I raised the mods flag as I couldn't raise the need details or clarity flag. I flagged it as such because of a comment under my answer I quote: *"FOR THE READERS: if you read, can you also write me your answer? I would like to deal with several different answers. thank you"* to me it sounded as if the user was here to purchase an answer, not seek help.

Comment: @Art flags are only shown to moderators, not the authors of the question.  If you weren't asking for the question to be closed, it's unclear what you'd like a moderator to do.  The flag text, for reference: "This question lacks absolute clarity; it's not specific, forcing me to delete two well-written answers. The author is expecting to write code for him/her, not trying to seek any help, or looking to learn, looking into comments under my deleted answers'. I cannot flag it as needing improvement, as this has a bounty."

Comment: Note also that "needs improvement" flags serve to recommend that the question be closed.

Comment: @RyanM Hmmm. I haven't raised a mod flag before on a question. I wasn't sure what to expect.